# Element is present but `Set.contains(element)` returns false

Tags: java, hash, set, contains, hashset

**How can an element *not* be contained in the original set but in its *unmodified* copy?**

The original set does not contain the element while its copy does. [See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBIOW.png)

The following method returns `true`, although it should always return `false`. The implementation of `c` and `clusters` is in both cases `HashSet`.

```
public static boolean confumbled(Set<String> c, Set<Set<String>> clusters) {
    return (!clusters.contains(c) && new HashSet<>(clusters).contains(c));
}
```

Debugging has shown that the element *is* contained in the original, but `Set.contains(element)` returns `false` for some reason. [See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l10NN.png)

**Could somebody please explain to me what's going on?**

Comment: I don't see any evidence that `clusters` is a HashSet. It could use a different `contains` method

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you change an element in the `Set` (in your case the elements are `Set<String>`, so adding or removing a String will change them), `Set.contains(element)` may fail to locate it, since the `hashCode` of the element will be different than what it was when the element was first added to the `HashSet`.

When you create a new `HashSet` containing the elements of the original one, the elements are added based on their current `hashCode`, so `Set.contains(element)` will return true for the new `HashSet`.

You should avoid putting mutable instances in a `HashSet` (or using them as keys in a `HashMap`), and if you can't avoid it, make sure you remove the element before you mutate it and re-add it afterwards. Otherwise your `HashSet` will be broken.

An example :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("one");
set.add("two");
Set<Set<String>> setOfSets = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
setOfSets.add(set);
boolean found = setOfSets.contains(set); // returns true
set.add("three");
Set<Set<String>> newSetOfSets = new HashSet<Set<String>>(setOfSets);
found = setOfSets.contains(set); // returns false
found = newSetOfSets.contains(set); // returns true
```

Answer (score 8):

The most common reason for this is that the element or key was altered after insertion resulting in a corruption of the underlying data structure.

note: when you add a reference to a `Set<String>` to another `Set<Set<String>>` you are adding a copy of the *reference*, the underlying`Set<String>` is not copied and if you alter it these changes which affect the `Set<Set<String>>` you put it into.

e.g.

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
Set<Set<String>> ss = new HashSet<>();
ss.add(s);
assert ss.contains(s);

// altering the set after adding it corrupts the HashSet
s.add("Hi");
// there is a small chance it may still find it.
assert !ss.contains(s);

// build a correct structure by copying it.
Set<Set<String>> ss2 = new HashSet<>(ss);
assert ss2.contains(s);

s.add("There");
// not again.
assert !ss2.contains(s);
```

Answer (score 8):

If the primary `Set` was a `TreeSet` (or perhaps some other `NavigableSet`) then it is possible, if your objects are imperfectly compared, for this to happen.

The critical point is that `HashSet.contains` looks like:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
}
```

and `map` is a `HashMap` and `HashMap.containsKey` looks like:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}
```

so it uses the `hashCode` of the key to check for presence.

A `TreeSet` however uses a `TreeMap` internally and it's `containsKey` looks like:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    ...
```

So it uses a `Comparator` to find the key.

So, in summary, if your `hashCode` method does not agree with your `Comparator.compareTo` method (say `compareTo` returns `1` while `hashCode` returns different values) then you will see this kind of obscure behaviour.

```
class BadThing {

    final int hash;

    public BadThing(int hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BadThing{" + "hash=" + hash + '}';
    }

}

public void test() {
    Set<BadThing> primarySet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<BadThing>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(BadThing o1, BadThing o2) {
            return 1;
        }
    });
    // Make the things.
    BadThing bt1 = new BadThing(1);
    primarySet.add(bt1);
    BadThing bt2 = new BadThing(2);
    primarySet.add(bt2);
    // Make the secondary set.
    Set<BadThing> secondarySet = new HashSet<>(primarySet);
    // Have a poke around.
    test(primarySet, bt1);
    test(primarySet, bt2);
    test(secondarySet, bt1);
    test(secondarySet, bt2);
}

private void test(Set<BadThing> set, BadThing thing) {
    System.out.println(thing + " " + (set.contains(thing) ? "is" : "NOT") + " in <" + set.getClass().getSimpleName() + ">" + set);
}
```

prints

```
BadThing{hash=1} NOT in <TreeSet>[BadThing{hash=1}, BadThing{hash=2}]
BadThing{hash=2} NOT in <TreeSet>[BadThing{hash=1}, BadThing{hash=2}]
BadThing{hash=1} is in <HashSet>[BadThing{hash=1}, BadThing{hash=2}]
BadThing{hash=2} is in <HashSet>[BadThing{hash=1}, BadThing{hash=2}]
```

so even though the object **is** in the `TreeSet` it is not finding it because the comparator never returns `0`. However, once it is in the `HashSet` all is fine because `HashSet` uses `hashCode` to find it and they behave in a valid way.